# Angular Variable Stays Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote the following code:

**authentication.service.ts**

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private readonly ACCESS_TOKEN = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';
  private readonly REFRESH_TOKEN = 'REFRESH_TOKEN';
  private loggedUser: string;
  public userId : number; 
  public user : User; 
  private API_URL= environment.API_URL;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router:Router, private userService : UserService) {}

  login(username: string, password:string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.API_URL + 'token/', { username: username, password: password })
      .pipe(
        tap(tokens => this.doLoginUser(username, tokens)),
        mapTo(true),
        catchError(error => {
          return of(false);
        }));
  }

  logout() {
    this.doLogoutUser();
  }

  decodeJwt(token){
    let decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    this.userId = decoded.user_id; 
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return !!this.getAccessToken();
  }

  isStaff() {
    return this.user.is_staff; 
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.API_URL + "token/refresh/", {
      'refresh': this.getRefreshToken()
    }).pipe(
      tap((tokens: Tokens) => {
      this.storeJwtToken(tokens.access);
      }),
      mapTo(true), 
      catchError(error => {
        this.doLogoutUser(); 
        this.router.navigate(["/login"])
        return of(false); 
      }
      )
      );
  }

  getAccessToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.ACCESS_TOKEN);
  }

  getUserData(){
    this.userService.getUser(this.userId).subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data.results[0]
      console.log(this.user)
    })
  }

  private doLoginUser(username: string, tokens: Tokens) {
    this.loggedUser = username;
    this.storeTokens(tokens);
    this.decodeJwt(tokens.access); 
    this.getUserData(); 
  }

  private doLogoutUser() {
    this.loggedUser = null;
    this.removeTokens();
  }

  private getRefreshToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.REFRESH_TOKEN);
  }

  private storeJwtToken(accessToken: string) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
  }

  private storeTokens(tokens: Tokens) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.ACCESS_TOKEN, tokens.access);
    localStorage.setItem(this.REFRESH_TOKEN, tokens.refresh);
  }

  private removeTokens() {
    localStorage.removeItem(this.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    localStorage.removeItem(this.REFRESH_TOKEN);
  }
}
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public authService : AuthenticationService, private router : Router) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.authService.isStaff())
  }

  logOut(){
    this.authService.logout() 
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
export class UserService {
  private API_URL= environment.API_URL;

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(page:number=1){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.API_URL + 'users/', {
      params: new HttpParams().set("page", page.toString())
    });
  }

  register(data:User) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.API_URL + 'users/', data)
  }

  getUser(id : number){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.API_URL + 'users/' + id.toString())
  }
}
```

Upon logging in the `getUser`-function is called but when I check the console the navbar constructor gives the error that `this.user` from the `isStaff`-function in the `authentication.service.ts` is undefined. The user endpoint works properly because when I console log the value of `data.results[0]` within the subscribe function it shows the data of the user.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think this is due to synchronicity. Functions are being called before values emit. Try converting logic dependent Observables `toPromise()` and then calling the private function. You might want to sprinkle in some `async/await` as well.

Comment: @jamessmallred Do you have any example of this?

Comment: It's not clear from your code whether the babar is created after the user is logged in or before. Try creating a stackblitz demo.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the variable is `undefined`.

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private readonly ACCESS_TOKEN = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';
  private readonly REFRESH_TOKEN = 'REFRESH_TOKEN';
  private loggedUser: string;
  public userId : number;
  public user : User;   =======> UNDEFINED
  private API_URL= environment.API_URL;
```

The this.user will be defined only after the `login` service and the `getUserData` is complete. Not before that. But I think the `Navbar` component is initialized even before the service calls are complete.

In the code above, I don't see any call made to the `AuthenticationService.login` function. So I see 2 options,

Option 1 -> Do not show the `navbar` component till the user is logged in.

Option 2 -> Throw an event from the `AuthenticationService` once the user is logged in. Subscribe to that event in the `navbar` component before accessing the this.user.

Comment: Even when the user is logged in the console still throws the same error. Saying that the variable is still undefined

Comment: Are you saying the navbar component is initialized only after the calls to login and this.userService.getUser are complete? If so, did you check what is the response you received from this.userService.getUser? It looks like you are assigning that to this.user.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure but this code doesn't make sense to me: `this.authService.isStaff()`

you appear to be calling a service which will check this.user, whether it's defined or not, which is not a good idea.

instead shouldn't you be using the service to get a user, and then passing the `this.user` into the navbar component and then checking directly if `this.user.is_staff`?

just an idea.

Comment: Doesn't that means that when I need to user variable I need to call it over and over again

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think generally you log in and then save the log-in info to either memory or sessionStorage or localStorage, so you don't need to re-log-in every time you change pages. once you have your user info saved to an object, you should be able to pass that object into your navbar. but your navbar itself should not be calling your service.